# How can I use a "<" character in sed?

Tags: linux, command-line, sed

I am trying to replace this line with a `<?php` tag with `sed` using the command:

```
find . -name "*.php" -type f -exec sed -i '/if(!isset($GLOBALS/<?php/d' {} \;
```

When I run the script, it generates an error

```
unknown command: `<' sed
```

How can I make the sed command-line use a regExp to escape the character `<`?

Comment: -1 if you're going to ask a question then use a simplified example to illustrate your question.

Comment: @barlop I understand the need for [SSCCEs](http://sscce.org/) but in this case the problem is quite apparent. Not sure how it could be simplified.

Comment: @slhck one can simplify it and still get the same error, so he still wants the find, then `$ find . -name "*.php" -type f -exec sed -i '/ifissetLOBALS/<asdf/d' {} \;`  gives the same error.(and that is simpler as it shows the exclamation mark and brackets aren't anything to do with the error)  And then since that gives the same error so does `$ find . -name "*.php" -type f -exec sed -i '/hhjgh/<asdf/d' {} \;`  that for sure simplifies it(undisputable). and (since he knows it's a sed issue) one can simplify it further eliminating the find,`$ echo adsf | sed -i '/sdf/<'` same error produced.

Comment: the syntax you are using for sed is wrong and it looks like you don't even know how to do something like echo abc| sed "s/a/z/"  I suggest you figure out how to do something as simple as replace the letter 'a' with 'z', before you start wondering why you're not replacing the > sign.

Comment: Crossposting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26306171/3776858

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the `<` character with with a `\`.

Comment: see g-man's answer, he already have the < escaped by single quotes.

Comment: @barlop g-man's answer works also, but it's difficult for me to see into the future.

Comment: the questioner included quotes so already had it escaped, gman got it that being, correcting the questioner's sed syntax

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? 
If you want to replace `if(!isset($GLOBALS` with `<?php`, you should be saying

```
's/if(!isset($GLOBALS/<?php/'
```

i.e., put an `s` at the beginning of the command, and get rid of the `d` at the end.